# how to match domain with subdomain in a list of domains with regex?

Tags: javascript

```
const valid = (domain) => domain.match(/^(test.com|example.com)$/);
```

these are my cases

```
valid("test.com") // true
valid("something.test.com") //false
```

how can I tweak the regexp to return true for something.test.com? thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current regex essentially forces the beginning and end of the match. If you want, like you say, to match also for subdomains, then you need to account for that too, with something like this:

```
/^(\S+\.)*(test.com|example.com)$/
```

which essentially says that "the first word and dot are optional".

See it in action here: https://regex101.com/r/xnyA3i/2

Comment: will that work for anything.test.com and anything.example.com ?

Comment: `^` is redundant - you'll select everything to the beginning of any continuous string (without spaces) even without the carat

Comment: @RandyCasburn Yes, I guess that can be eliminated.